# Access jframe from another function and add jpanel into it - java swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to achieve a specific GUI, BUT I am failed to insert a JPanel into my jframe which is initialized in another function, any idea how to do so ?

here is my code :

```
public class CDRTable {
    int totalRecords;
    private final String[] columnNames = { "Year", "String", "Comment" };
    private final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(null, columnNames) {
        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
            return (column == 0) ? Integer.class : Object.class;
        }
    };
    private final TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
    private final JTable table = new JTable(model);
    private final JButton first = new JButton(new AbstractAction("|<") {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            currentPageIndex = 1;
            initFilterAndButton();
        }
    });
    private final JButton prev = new JButton(new AbstractAction("<") {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            currentPageIndex -= 1;
            initFilterAndButton();
        }
    });
    private final JButton next = new JButton(new AbstractAction(">") {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            currentPageIndex += 1;
            initFilterAndButton();
        }
    });
    private final JButton last = new JButton(new AbstractAction(">|") {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            currentPageIndex = maxPageIndex;
            initFilterAndButton();
        }
    });
    private final JTextField field = new JTextField(2);
    private final JLabel label = new JLabel();

    public JComponent makeUI() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);

        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:file:G:/hs_data/h2_db/test", "sa", "sa");

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM cdr LIMIT 1000");

        totalRecords = 1000;
        for (int i = 0; i < totalRecords; i++) {
            model.addRow(new Object[] { 0,0,0 });
        }
        table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

        JPanel po = new JPanel();
        po.add(field);
        po.add(label);
        JPanel box = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 4, 2, 2));
        for (JComponent r : Arrays.asList(first, prev, po, next, last)) {
            box.add(r);
        }

        int rowCount = model.getRowCount();
        int v = rowCount % itemsPerPage == 0 ? 0 : 1;
        maxPageIndex = rowCount / itemsPerPage + v;
        initFilterAndButton();
        label.setText(String.format("/ %d", maxPageIndex));
        KeyStroke enter = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);
        field.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(enter, "Enter");
        field.getActionMap().put("Enter", new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    int v = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
                    if (v > 0 && v <= maxPageIndex) {
                        currentPageIndex = v;
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                initFilterAndButton();
            }
        });

        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p.add(box, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        p.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        return p;
    }

    private final int itemsPerPage = 100;
    private int maxPageIndex;
    private int currentPageIndex = 1;

    private void initFilterAndButton() {
        sorter.setRowFilter(new RowFilter<TableModel, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public boolean include(Entry<? extends TableModel, ? extends Integer> entry) {
                int ti = currentPageIndex - 1;
                int ei = entry.getIdentifier();
                return ti * itemsPerPage <= ei && ei < ti * itemsPerPage + itemsPerPage;
            }
        });
        first.setEnabled(currentPageIndex > 1);
        prev.setEnabled(currentPageIndex > 1);
        next.setEnabled(currentPageIndex < maxPageIndex);
        last.setEnabled(currentPageIndex < maxPageIndex);
        field.setText(Integer.toString(currentPageIndex));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    CDRTable obj = new CDRTable();
                    obj.createAndShowGUI();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void createAndShowGUI() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(new CDRTable().makeUI());
        f.setBounds(30, 50, 1300, 600);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }


}
```

When i try to access the jframe initialized in `createAndShowGUI()` from `public JComponent makeUI()` it shows an error

> f cannot be resolved

I am very new to JAVA, so please ignore if you feel irritated by my question :)

Comment: I don't see `f` in your makeUI. You should probably make `f` a field instead of a local variable in the createAndShowGui() method.

Comment: You are only defining JFrame f inside your static createAndShowGUI method. It is not accessible outside! Read something about the basics of visibility and object orientation in java

Comment: I have tried to declare and define `JFrame f = new JFrame("CDR TABLE"); `in my main class, but then it forced me to make it static, which completely change the entire code. Don't know what to do

Comment: @Luftbaum I have changed the code, please check now. I have create object of main class and then call the createAndShowGUI from that function and remove static but frame is still not accessible from any other function

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, I achieved what I wanted, so I thought I should put the answer my self here.

```
public class CDRTable {
    //JFrame f;
    int totalRecords;
    private final String[] columnNames = { "ANUMBER", "BNUMBER", "DATETIME" };
    private final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(null, columnNames) {
        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
            return (column == 0) ? Integer.class : Object.class;
        }
    };
    private final TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
    private final JTable table = new JTable(model);
    private final JButton first = new JButton(new AbstractAction("|<") {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            currentPageIndex = 1;
            initFilterAndButton();
        }
    });
    private final JButton prev = new JButton(new AbstractAction("<") {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            currentPageIndex -= 1;
            initFilterAndButton();
        }
    });
    private final JButton next = new JButton(new AbstractAction(">") {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            currentPageIndex += 1;
            initFilterAndButton();
        }
    });
    private final JButton last = new JButton(new AbstractAction(">|") {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            currentPageIndex = maxPageIndex;
            initFilterAndButton();
        }
    });
    private final JTextField field = new JTextField(2);
    private final JLabel label = new JLabel();

    public JComponent makeUI(Container f) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);

        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:file:G:/hs_data/h2_db/test", "sa", "sa");

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM cdr LIMIT 1000");

        totalRecords = 1000;
        for (int i = 0; i < totalRecords; i++) {
            model.addRow(new Object[] { 0,0,0 });
        }
        table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

        JPanel po = new JPanel();
        po.add(field);
        po.add(label);
        JPanel box = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 4, 2, 2));
        for (JComponent r : Arrays.asList(first, prev, po, next, last)) {
            box.add(r);
        }
        int rowCount = model.getRowCount();
        int v = rowCount % itemsPerPage == 0 ? 0 : 1;
        maxPageIndex = rowCount / itemsPerPage + v;
        initFilterAndButton();
        label.setText(String.format("/ %d", maxPageIndex));
        KeyStroke enter = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);
        field.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(enter, "Enter");
        field.getActionMap().put("Enter", new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    int v = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
                    if (v > 0 && v <= maxPageIndex) {
                        currentPageIndex = v;
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                initFilterAndButton();
            }
        });

        UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selected", Color.lightGray);
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        f.add(tabbedPane);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("TABLE", null, panel, null);
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("GRAPH", null, panel_1, null);
        panel_1.setBackground(Color.white);

        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane();
        panel.add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        scrollpane.setViewportView(table);

        table.getTableHeader().setBackground(new Color(26,82,118));
        table.getTableHeader().setForeground(Color.white);
        table.getTableHeader().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 40));
        table.setRowHeight(30);

        first.setBackground(new Color(84, 153, 199));
        prev.setBackground(new Color(84, 153, 199));
        next.setBackground(new Color(84, 153, 199));
        last.setBackground(new Color(84, 153, 199));

        first.setForeground(Color.white);
        prev.setForeground(Color.white);
        next.setForeground(Color.white);
        last.setForeground(Color.white);

        panel.add(box);
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        return scrollpane;

    }

    private final int itemsPerPage = 100;
    private int maxPageIndex;
    private int currentPageIndex = 1;

    private void initFilterAndButton() {
        sorter.setRowFilter(new RowFilter<TableModel, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public boolean include(Entry<? extends TableModel, ? extends Integer> entry) {
                int ti = currentPageIndex - 1;
                int ei = entry.getIdentifier();
                return ti * itemsPerPage <= ei && ei < ti * itemsPerPage + itemsPerPage;
            }
        });
        first.setEnabled(currentPageIndex > 1);
        prev.setEnabled(currentPageIndex > 1);
        next.setEnabled(currentPageIndex < maxPageIndex);
        last.setEnabled(currentPageIndex < maxPageIndex);
        field.setText(Integer.toString(currentPageIndex));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    CDRTable obj = new CDRTable();
                    obj.createAndShowGUI();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void createAndShowGUI() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("CDR TABLE");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(new CDRTable().makeUI(f));
        f.setBounds(30, 50, 1300, 600);
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }


}
```

Comment: easiest way is to declare your jframe as a public accesible field after you declare the name of your class, and instantiate it in your main method, this way, your JFrame variable can be accessible in all of your methods